# Angular2 - How should I implement Google instant preview using Angular2?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement the Google Instant preview on my Angular project. However, when I use the `iframe` tag, it shows nothing.

html code -

```
<div class="text-result" *ngIf="Display('all')">
                <div *ngFor="let item of items$|async" class="result">
                    <div class="title">
                        <a href="{{item.link}}">{{item.title}}</a>
                        <div class="box">
                            <iframe src="{{item.link}}" width="500px" height="500px"></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="link">
                        <p>{{item.link}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {{item.pubDate|date:'fullDate'}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

css code -

```
.box{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

a:hover + .box,.box:hover{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid XSS attack, angular does not allow dynamicly binding to iframe's `src` attribute. You can use the [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html) class to allow an url.
You need to inject [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html) and use the `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` method.

```js
constructor(domsanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    let url = "http://some-random-url.tld";
    this.myUrl = this.domsanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
```

and in your template:

```html
<iframe [src]="myUrl"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you for giving time to my question. Actually, I'm fetching the results from a web service. So, to fetch links I use `{{item.link}}` . As you said, can I write it as `let url = "{{item.link}}"`? or I have to write it like this - `let url = "http://web-service-url.tld"`

Comment: I don't know you code, so maybe. You can do what you want as long as you pass a `SafeResourceUrl` and not a `string` to iframes's `src`.